# @font-face looks blurry on mac

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts

I’m loading a font using @font-face on my Website. Everything is working well on Windows but apparently not so on Macs. On Macs the font renders super blurry.

I don’t have access to a Mac myself, but I’ve got several colleagues to check for me and send me a screenshot. I’m attaching screenshots from both operating systems below.

[image]

This is the code I’m using to load the font:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: HelveticaNeue;
    src: url('//wasawards.com/wp-content/themes/wasawards/fonts/HelveticaNeue-BlackCond.ttf'),
}
```

Any ideas what might be happening or what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The articles below tell why and how to resolve the issue:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1347149?start=0&tstart=0
http://www.creativebloq.com/computer-arts/helvetica-wrong-choice-mac-os-81412755

Answer (score 0):

You may need to adjust your font-smoothing settings for certain fonts, or it could be your font is not terribly well constructed and Macs aren't handling that as you would like.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-smooth